# android throw InflateException binary xml file line : Error inflating class fragment

Tags: android, fragment

I got a Activity class which implement a Actionbar with two Tabs. Each Tab is calling a other Fragment??.class over the TabListener. If I start the Application the FragmentXY.class is called. I can switch to the second Tab without any problem. But if I switch back to the first Tab which contains the two other fragments as a split-screen, the application crashed and throw the Error :InflateException binary xml file line : Error inflating class fragment

```
tab = actionBar
    .newTab()
    .setText("My Box")
    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_help)
    .setTabListener(new MyTabListener<FragmentXY>(this, "myXY",FragmentXY.class));
    actionBar.addTab(tab);

tab = actionBar
    .newTab()
    .setText("QR-Code")
    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_add)
    .setTabListener(new MyTabListener<FragmentXYZ>(this, "barcode",FragmentXYZ.class));

actionBar.addTab(tab);
```

Each Fragment.class is calling a xml resource which contain once two other fragments or only one Fragment.

FragmentXY.class

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.first_tab, container, false);
        return view;
    }
```

first_tab.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <fragment
        android:name="com.febro.myfragmenttest.ListFragment"
        android:id="@+id/listFragment"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        class="com.febro.myfragmenttest.ListFragment" ></fragment>

    <fragment
        android:name="com.febro.myfragmenttest.DetailFragment"
        android:id="@+id/detailFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.febro.myfragmenttest.DetailFragment" >
    </fragment>

</LinearLayout>
```

Is it a problem with the callback-methode?

Here is the full error report from logcat:

```
09-12 19:57:06.300: D/AndroidRuntime(2799): Shutting down VM
09-12 19:57:06.300: W/dalvikvm(2799): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4015d760)
09-12 19:57:06.310: E/AndroidRuntime(2799): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-12 19:57:06.310: E/AndroidRuntime(2799): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class fragment
09-12 19:57:06.310: E/AndroidRuntime(2799):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:688)
09-12 19:57:06.310: E/AndroidRuntime(2799):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:724)
09-12 19:57:06.310: E/AndroidRuntime(2799):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:479)
09-12 19:57:06.310: E/AndroidRuntime(2799):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:391)
09-12 19:57:06.310: E/AndroidRuntime(2799):     at com.febro.myfragmenttest.FragmentXY.onCreateView(FragmentXY.java:26)
09-12 19:57:06.310: E/AndroidRuntime(2799):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:776)
09-12 19:57:06.310: E/AndroidRuntime(2799):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.attachFragment(FragmentManager.java:1133)
09-12 19:57:06.310: E/AndroidRuntime(2799):     at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:628)
09-12 19:57:06.310: E/AndroidRuntime(2799):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1309)
09-12 19:57:06.310: E/AndroidRuntime(2799):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:398)
09-12 19:57:06.310: E/AndroidRuntime(2799):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
09-12 19:57:06.310: E/AndroidRuntime(2799):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-12 19:57:06.310: E/AndroidRuntime(2799):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
09-12 19:57:06.310: E/AndroidRuntime(2799):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4126)
09-12 19:57:06.310: E/AndroidRuntime(2799):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-12 19:57:06.310: E/AndroidRuntime(2799):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
09-12 19:57:06.310: E/AndroidRuntime(2799):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:844)
09-12 19:57:06.310: E/AndroidRuntime(2799):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
09-12 19:57:06.310: E/AndroidRuntime(2799):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-12 19:57:06.310: E/AndroidRuntime(2799): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #6: Duplicate id 0x7f090008, tag null, or parent id 0xffffffff with another fragment for com.febro.myfragmenttest.ListFragment
09-12 19:57:06.310: E/AndroidRuntime(2799):     at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4182)
09-12 19:57:06.310: E/AndroidRuntime(2799):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:664)
09-12 19:57:06.310: E/AndroidRuntime(2799):     ... 18 more
09-12 19:57:06.320: W/ActivityManager(302):   Force finishing activity com.febro.myfragmenttest/.ActionbarMain
09-12 19:57:06.400: D/dalvikvm(302): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 13157K, 52% free 12567K/26055K, paused 68ms
```

Comment: Please post all of your LogCat errors.

Answer (score 4):

simply extends
 your class extends FragmentActivity

instead of extends Activity

Answer (score 0):

I've run into the same error (different implementation).  The underlying cause was because the View returned in the inflated fragment class (i.e. returned from the fragment's onCreateView() method) is invalid or you did not implement the onCreateView method itself.

In your case, check the view you're returning in com.febro.myfragmenttest.ListFragment and verify that it's valid.  I'd suggest setting a breakpoint in the onCreateView method.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
<fragment
    android:name="com.febro.myfragmenttest.ListFragment"
    android:id="@+id/listFragment"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    class="com.febro.myfragmenttest.ListFragment" ></fragment>
```

In this tag, you have both android:name and class set to the same thing. Since these map to the same thing, you should only use one. This is why this appeared in the stack trace:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #6: *Duplicate id* ....
```

In the [Fragment](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) android guide, they use these interchangeably for the same purpose.

Answer (score -1):

You have to write

```
super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
```

in your onCreateView method.

Comment: He's inflating his own view rather than using onCreateView